# Do I buy the "regular" or TPMS tire-valve-stem caps for my 2004 Acura MDX?

Tags: tires, tire-pressure

I am interested in buying plastic ones. For example, I'd like to know whether I should get the "regular" caps or special ones with the word TPMS in the product title.

If we look at the two kinds of caps that are sold by a vendor, the bottom one is the TPMS pack and it also costs more. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge, a valve stem cap is a valve stem cap ... whether it says TPMS or not on it, shouldn't make a difference. If the TPMS is built into the valve stem (like quite a few are), everything is in the inside of the tire. The stem itself is industry standard in size/shape. Any regular valve stem cap should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added a photo to my question where it showed the two kinds of caps sold by a vendor.

Comment: First of all, I hope you didn't use Slime in your tires which have a TPMS in them, because that's a sure fire for disaster with them. Maybe you're just showing what you've found ... dunno. I'll reiterate about the caps themselves, if you just get some standard valve stem caps, they should work just fine.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Slime is just a brand. I have Michelin Primacy MXV4 tires and the TPMS comes with my Acura MDX. The screenshot I posted in my question shows the caps I was thinking of buying from Autozone.

Comment: Yes, Slime is a brand, however, the brand is synonymous with goop you put *inside* your tire to seal leaks/holes. The problem is, when you put it inside of tires with TPMS, it has a propensity to ruin the sensors.

Comment: I see; got it. I was looking at Slime-branded caps. My tires are fine. I think I will buy the one without the "TPMS" word in the product title. Thanks.